# What can cause content of a file in git head to be different from that of the last commit?

Tags: git, tfs, msysgit

Using TFS 2013 with Git.

Somehow a single commit seems to have "detached" some commits made earlier. I'll try to explain:

File A was changed in a commit on day1 and again on day2. A commit touching some files other than A is made on day3.
With that commit, File A is now back to the version of day1.

Observations:

- HEAD version of A is equal to day1 version (unexpected).
- TFS web interface content tab for file A shows the version from day1 (unexpected).
- `git log A` shows only commit from day1 (unexpected).
- TFS web interface history tab for file A shows both day1 and day2 commit. Contents of last commit (day2) shows the latest version of the file (expected).

If I `git checkout day2sha` I get the day2 version, so the commit is in there somewhere.

What's happening?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is what changes were made on day3 ? beside other changes, anyone did a checkout on File A ? a revert maybe ?

Comment: When you push the files other than A, did you get conflict?

Comment: A revert - wouldn't that result in an entry in git log?

Comment: It's possible there was a conflict. Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: @Thomsen, is it possible that when you modify files on day3, you didn't get pull the latest version of your project?